# How do I avoid call to same method only if arguments are same, on different threads

Tags: java, multithreading

```
private void startProcess(Long id)
        throws UnAuthorizedException, UnAuthenticatedException, InvalidRequestException {
    ......

        createComponent(Long id);

    ......
}
```

This method createComponent or the startProcess itself should not be called again on separate thread, if the id is same

Comment: If `startProcess` returns quickly (which the name suggests) then you can just block *any* concurrent access with `synchronized` or similar. If this is not acceptable for you, can you explain why?

Comment: In my case startProcess takes around 1-2s to complete, dont want to block this for other calls by using syncronized

Comment: @MarkJeronimus what if I use something like syncronized block with unique lock for different ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your method takes time and you want to block concurrent access only when the ID is the same (or any combination of parameters) then you need to store a lock for every ID (or any combination of parameters).

These locks can be stored in a `Map`.

If it's just an ID of type `Long` you can use it directly as the Map's key. If you have multiple parameters, wrap them in a custom class along with the required equals/hashcode methods.

```
private Map<Long, Lock> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(100);

private void startProcess(Long id) {
    Lock lock = locks.computeIfAbsent(id, id2 -> new ReentrantLock());

    lock.lock();
    try {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Starting  " + id + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Done with " + id + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
        locks.remove(lock);
    }
}
```

Called with:

```
new Thread(() -> startProcess(1L), "A").start();
new Thread(() -> startProcess(1L), "B").start();
new Thread(() -> startProcess(2L), "C").start();
```

this is one possible output:

```
1595950202869 Starting  1 on thread A
1595950202879 Starting  2 on thread C
1595950204870 Done with 1 on thread A
1595950204870 Starting  1 on thread B
1595950204879 Done with 2 on thread C
1595950206870 Done with 1 on thread B
```

### [Edit] Sample code for custom class for parameters:

```
private Map<ProcessParams, Lock> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(100);

private void startProcess(long id, String name) {
    Lock lock = locks.computeIfAbsent(new ProcessParams(id, name), id2 -> new ReentrantLock());

    lock.lock();
    try {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Starting  " + name + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Done with " + name + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
        locks.remove(lock);
    }
}

public static class ProcessParams {
    private final long   id;
    private final String name;

    public ProcessParams(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name, "name");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;

        if (!(o instanceof ProcessParams))
            return false;

        ProcessParams other = (ProcessParams)o;
        return id == other.id && name.equals(other.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashCode = 0x811C9DC5;
        hashCode = 0x01000193 * (hashCode ^ Long.hashCode(id));
        hashCode = 0x01000193 * (hashCode ^ name.hashCode());
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! This seems like what I was looking for.

Comment: what is this locks variable type of?
Also if now instead of Id i have a custom class object to compare? Can you explain with a sample code?

Comment: Yes `locks` variable was accidentally missing